# Activerecord::Datetime>objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

a maximum of 15 reservations can be made
per day per restaurant.
No more than 20 reservations should be allowed for a single day across all restaurants.

I want to be able to make a "condition" with activerecord where the reservation date is equal to the date that is passed by the parameter

```rb
def create
  @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
  @restaurant_date = @reservation.startreservation.strftime("%F")
    
  pp @restaurant_date

  @restaurant_reservation = Reservation.where(restaurant_id:    @reservation.restaurant_id).where(:startreservation.strftime("%F") => @restaurant_date )

  pp @restaurant_reservation

    
  # if @restaurant_reservation == 15
  #   redirect_to restaurants_path , alert: "Reservation was not created." 
  # else
  if @reservation.save
    redirect_to reservation_url(@reservation), notice: "Reservation was successfully created." 
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity 
  end  
  #end
end
```

It may be that I did not explain the problem well, any questions I will answer at the moment. :)

Comment: With the right relations here you should be able to do `restaurant.reservations` instead of `Reservation.where(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is business logic (checking for 15 registrations), so the best practice is place it in model or service (not in controller), for example use custom validation in model:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validate do |reservation|
    if Reservation.where(restaurant_id: reservation.restaurant_id,
                         startreservation: reservation.restaurant_date).size >= 15
      errors.add(:startreservation, :to_much, message: 'Too much on this date.')
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

... controller:

```
def create
  @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

  if @reservation.save
    redirect_to reservation_url(@reservation), notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity 
  end  
end
```

<kbd>[ActiveRecord Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-add)</kbd>

Comment: thank you, I have not found out the answer, I had already solved it from the controller. I will save your answer for future problems

Answer (score 0):

```
@restaurant_date = @reservation.startreservation.to_date
    

    *@restaurant_reservation = Reservation.where(restaurant_id: @reservation.restaurant_id).where(startreservation: (@restaurant_date..@restaurant_date+1) ).count
    
    if @restaurant_reservation == 15
      redirect_to restaurants_path , alert: "Reservation can't be created." 
    else*
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).